# Custom Variable in AppServiceProvider Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel

I want use a variable from my database to set a folder for custom views.

```
"class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider"

$ActiveProject = ThemeConfig::where('module_type',"project")->where('active',"1")->first()->file;
```

After this, I get an active project name (like Nshop), and I want to set it in:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app['view']->addNamespace('Projects', base_path() . '/Projects/'.$ActiveProject.'/Views');
}
```

But I get an error.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: What is the error? Add that to question. Please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: error is (Call to a member function connection() on null) because i can get data from database in public function register

Comment: Try to replace `ThemeConfig::where` with `\DB::table('theme_configs')->where` or the name of the database ThemeConfig refers to in your Model.

Comment: Dimitri Mostrey thanks its worcks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ORM Models in the AppServiceProvider doesn't work. This file is part of the boot process of Laravel where your models are not loaded yet. But you can rely on functions that are part of the Laravel core concept.

```
$ActiveProject = ThemeConfig::where('module_type',"project")->where('active',"1")->first()->file;
```

Becomes

```
$ActiveProject = \DB::table('theme_configs')->where('module_type',"project")->where('active',"1")->first()->file;
```